# contravariance compilation exception with mono

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to compile the covariance/contravariance example in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

```
// Assignment compatibility.  
string str = "test";
// An object of a more derived type is assigned to an object of a less derived type.  
object obj = str;

// Covariance. 
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
// An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument  
// is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument.  
// Assignment compatibility is preserved. 
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;

// Contravariance.            
// Assume that the following method is in the class:  
// static void SetObject(object o) { } 
Action<object> actObject = SetObject;
// An object that is instantiated with a less derived type argument  
// is assigned to an object instantiated with a more derived type argument.  
// Assignment compatibility is reversed. 
Action<string> actString = actObject;
```

The issue is that I got two errors:

Example1.cs(22,39):

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 
>               `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` to 
>               `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>`. 
>               An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Example1.cs(40,36):

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Action<object>`to `System.Action<string>`

I could resolve the first issue with casting: 'IEnumerable objects = (IEnumerable)strings;', but I'm not sure how to resolve the second issue. Basically, I don't know why I got errors from the compilation of MSDN code.

I use mono `Mono C# compiler version 3.12.0.0` for the compilation. What might be wrong?

Comment: I think this has to with the [Liskov Substituion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and/or the fact that `IEnumerable<string>` does not derive from `IEnumerable<object>` for your first example.  A simple `var objects = strings.Cast<object>().Tolist()` would probably fix your first example.

Comment: This ability was added with C# 4, .NET 4.0, and would produce those errors in previous versions. Is your version of Mono targetting 4.0 features, or earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I used `gmcs` compiler, when I compile the code with `dmcs` or `mcs`, the code compiles fine.

From the mono page (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/)

```
gmcs: compiler to target the 2.0 mscorlib.
smcs: compiler to target the 2.1 mscorlib, to build Moonlight applications.
dmcs: compiler to target the 4.0 mscorlib.

Starting with Mono version 2.11 a new unified compiler mcs is available. 
It replaces all previous runtime specific compilers (gmcs, dmcs, smcs). 
They still exist (as scripts only) to ease the migration path to mcs 
but we strongly recommend to use mcs.
```